# Tweepy user id from mention

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using `tweepy` to set up a script that finds the latest mention of my username. From this, I want to retrieve the text of the tweet, and their twitter user name. However, I don't seem to be able to retrieve the actual @ username, only their id number. Any suggestions?

Below is my code. The question marks are where I need the proper syntax:

```
myMentions = tweepy.Cursor (api.mentions).items(1)

for mention in myMentions:
    statusText = mention.text
    statusUser = mention.????
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

Here's what works for me with the most recent `tweepy` version:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<consumer_key>, <consumer_secret>)
auth.set_access_token(<key>, <secret>)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

mentions = api.mentions_timeline(count=1)

for mention in mentions:
    print mention.text
    print mention.user.screen_name
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Lovely, code worked first time for me, in march 2014! :v

Comment: Can you please tell how to get  some ones mentions_time line using tweepy. like passing the parameter as Id=''

Comment: @alecxe is there any way we can sort of modify this to get the latest mentions?